# Guardar imagen en disco desde un array de NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pillow

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> a. Escriba una función en que implemente la transformación gamma de una imagen en escala de grises. La
>    función debe recibir como parámetros de entrada: una imagen en escala de grises (uint8) y el parámetro
>    gamma . El parámetro de salida de la función debe ser una imagen en escala de grises (uint8). Para ϒ
>    evitar perder precisión en el cálculo de los valores de niveles de grises, convierta la imagen a double
>    antes de calcular la transformación gamma. La imagen debe convertirse nuevamente a uint8 antes de
>    retornar de la función.
>
> b. Seleccione una imagen a color y aplique la transformación gamma 
>   para Y=0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1, 1.5,2.5, 5.0, 10.0, 25.0.

Este es un punto del taller de Visión Artificial, lo que pasa es que logro visualizar la imagen en la terminal, pero necesito es que la imagen quede guardada en mi PC y no sé por qué no me guarda.

Así tengo el código pero no sé qué me faltaría, o en qué fallo:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps #importe de libreria PIL
import numpy as np #importe de libreria numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #importe de libreria matplotlib
import sys #improte de libreria SYS

sys.path.append('D:\Vision')  #la ruta de los archivos USB
import tranformacion_lineal as trans
Im_g = Image.open('bears.jpg').convert('L')

Im_ga = np.double(np.array(Im_g)) #Transofrmacion de la imagen a DOUBLE
Im2 = trans.my_gamma( Im_ga, 0.05) #Aca se manda la imagen  y el valor para el exponente  al metodo para Y=0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1, 1.5,2.5, 5.0, 10.0, 25.0.
plt.gray()

plt.imshow(np.uint8(Im_ga)) # esta linea no es necesaria ya se esta transformado en my_gamma
plt.axis('off')
plt.figure()

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(Im2)
plt.axis('off')

Im_g = Image.save('D:\Vision')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intentas usar el método correcto, [Image.save](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save), pero no de la forma correcta. Se trata de un método de instancia de la clase `Image` que forma parte a su vez del módulo `PIL.Image` y debe usarse por tanto sobre una instancia de la misma, como la que retorna `PIL.Image.open`.

En tu caso, al hacer `Image.save('D:\Vision')`, intentas usar la función `save` del módulo `PIL.Image`, función que no existe, en vez del método de instancia `save` de la clase `PIL.Image.Image`.

Dado que tienes la imágen a guardar en un array de NumPy debes usar [`PIL.Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray),que retorna una instancia de `PIL.Image.Image` para posteriormente usar su método `save`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image



img = Image.open("bears.jpg").convert("L")
im_ga = np.double(np.array(img)) 
im_fin = np.uint8(im_ga)

res_img = Image.fromarray(im_fin, mode="L")
res_img.save("D:/Vision/result.jpg")
```

> **Nota:** Nunca debes usar la barra inclinada inversa (`\`) sin escapar en cadenas que representen una ruta, dicho carácter es usado para especificar secuencias de escape (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\U`, etc) por lo que ocasiona errores al interpretar la ruta o errores de sintaxis directamente. En su lugar escápala (`"D:\\Vision\\bears.jpg"`) o usa la barra inclinada que es universal: `"D:/Vision/bears.jpg"`. Usar cadenas raw (`r"D:\..."`) también es posible, pero en ciertas situaciones pueden causar también problemas si no se normaliza primero la ruta (`os.path.normpath`).

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya pude resolver el problema. Te lo agradezco. Saludos.